# How to keep encoded characters as is

Tags: python, html, http, httpwebrequest, beautifulsoup

I am receiving web response in different encoding using python and my expected output should have to same as given on the web page

Ex : Marc Barbé

The last character should remain same after the parsing of html response.

Currently I am using following code for this

```
unicode.join(u'\n',map(unicode,item))
```

In some cases when there is no special encoding is given it is throwing following error :
Ex: Markus Rygaard, Alberte Blichfeldt, Flemming Quist, Møller

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "BFICrawl.py", line 20, in <module>
    print attrName + " : " + attrValue
  File "C:\Python27\LIB\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\xf8' in position 6
0: character maps to <undefined>
```

I really not able to find the reason for the same. Is there any alternate way available for getting the same encoding content from web.

Comment: please post your os and version, as this might also depend on the terminal and os you are running in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have successfully obtained `unicode` objects from the web. You should not need to do things like `unicode.join(u'\n',map(unicode,item))`. The problem is happening when you try to output the unicode.

You are running your script in a Windows "Command Prompt" window. The script is printing to the console. The console encoding is `cp437`. That is a very limited (8-bit) encoding. It can't handle the second character in `Møller`, and an enormous bunch of other characters

Remedy: Run your script in IDLE (supplied with your Python) or some other IDE.

Alternatively, if you are printing to the console for debug purposes only, instead of `print foo` use `print repr(foo)`

Comment: Anyone got any ideas on why the Phantom Anonymous Drive-by Downvoter took a dislike to my answer?

Comment: No idea, because I think it's a decent answer myself.  +1ing.

Answer (score 1):

[Codepage 437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codepage_437) (which is being encoded into) doesn't know the `ø` character, therefore your string can't be encoded for output. The error message does say all this.

So the question is: Why are you trying to encode the string into a codepage used by DOS console windows?

Comment: He's not (consciously) trying to do that.